# How to get Xcode's list of Callers externally, to find methods w/o callers

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is it possible to get at Xcode's list of callers for a method externally (ideally from a Ruby or Python script)? Where does Xcode keep this information?

What I would like to achieve is to find methods that do not have any (known) caller, in an effort to track down "dead" code.

Here's a screenshot from the list of callers (taken from this SO entry: [XCode find caller functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038257/xcode-find-caller-functions/11112091#11112091)): [image: list of callers]

Comment: Since you mention ruby, the StarScope gem might be adaptable to what you want (https://rubygems.org/gems/starscope). It doesn't support Objective-C at the moment, but its architecture should make it easy to add.